# Does the free tier of Heroku apps support file upload?

Tags: node.js, heroku, upload, fs, multer

I am testing out a MEAN stack application. I have a Node.js backend which handles file upload (via `fs/multer`). However I'm receiving a 503 error when trying to hit it in production.

Locally everything is working fine. I am using Heroku's free tier; is that tier locked to not allow file upload?

The upload I'm trying currently (have tried several) is only 36kb (`.png`).

Went through my logs and found the 503-

`2018-10-26T20:39:24.352297+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/media/upload" host=www.example.co.uk request_id=5388711c-bc99-4e42-9dbd-7b645fbefb43 fwd="90.222.69.255" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=130ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
2018-10-26T20:39:24.306975+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:20) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
2018-10-26T20:39:24.307037+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:20) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
2018-10-26T20:39:24.318818+00:00 app[web.1]: fs.js:113
2018-10-26T20:39:24.318822+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;  // Forgot a callback but don't know where? Use NODE_DEBUG=fs
2018-10-26T20:39:24.318824+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-10-26T20:39:24.318826+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-10-26T20:39:24.318828+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir './uploads/18'`

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/287

Comment: I am already checking if the directory exists (then creating it if it does not) via this method- I believe the issue may be coming from me specifying the file path in a particular manner which is not acceptable (probably for very valid reasons) on the node deployment I have set up on heroku... I'm going to rewrite a load of this application to use external storage anyway (thanks to your recommendation) so I'll have to leave that how it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File uploads shouldn't generate HTTP 503 on their own. You should check your logs (via `heroku logs`) to get more information about what's failing. Having said that, even if you resolve this issue you'll probably need to make a fundamental change with the way you're handling file uploads.

All Heroku tiers have an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Any changes made to the filesystem are lost whenever your dyno restarts, which [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day).

The [official recommendation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) is to put uploaded files onto a third-party service like Amazon S3. The [`multer-s3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3) library should be able to help with that.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, great answer. External storage would be an improvement I agree, it is just a small application though so figured I could get away with storing locally. Have updated my question with the related logs I found on your suggestion. Appears to me the application cannot find/create the correct folder.

Comment: @jmcgrory, there's no way around the ephemeral filesystem if you store your files locally. If you're okay losing files regularly, maybe it's not a problem. It might be fine for temporary storage. But if you want to keep them you'll need to store them elsewhere.