# Uploading image and getting error 500 Internet Server after deploy in Heroku by Flask

Tags: python, heroku, python-tesseract

I have a Python app with Tesseract OCR. I run on my pc. It's work!

[image]
[image]

However, I need deploy to Heroku. I was setting **Aptfile, buildpack, TESSDATA_PREFIX** already (ref: [How to deploy pytesseract to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53363547/how-to-deploy-pytesseract-to-heroku)). It's done.

**Here is my console**

Heroku
https://image-text-try.herokuapp.com/

Github
https://github.com/b-bella/image_text_try

It can run but error after submitting upload image.

[image]
[image]

**Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.**

Could anyone see my coding on github & heroku and suggest how to fix about deploying to heroku?

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import shutil
import os
import uuid
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/app/.apt/usr/bin/tesseract'
#pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS'] = set(['png', 'jpeg', 'jpg','gif'])

APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'static').replace('\\','/')
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.files:
            file = request.files['file_image']

            if allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)

                temp_file = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename).replace('\\', '/')
                file.save(temp_file)

                pre_result = pytesseract.image_to_string(temp_file, lang='eng')

                return render_template('index.html', result=pre_result, filename=filename)

            else:
                return render_template('index.html', result='That file extension is not allowed', filename=file.filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: I suggest you add some granular logging statements to whatever function is handling this request (I'm guessing `upload_file()`).

Comment: Note also that [you shouldn't be storing uploaded files on your dyno's local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53016453/354577). See https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted